# What was the first film to include a post-credits scene?

Tags: first-appearance, credits

We can see post-credits scenes in almost every Marvel movie - Avengers, Iron Man, and so on. Marvel make the post-credits scenes so interesting that we wait until after the movie ends just to see the post-credits scenes.

When did this idea of post-credits scenes first arise, and in which movie?